# self.navigationItem.titleView setNeedsDisplay slow to refresh when coming from a async queue

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm displaying a long list of items that I need to sort with 3 index (name, date, id). I then display the list with a UISegmentControl in self.navigationItem.titleView. The user can use that control to select which sort order he wants to display.
The user then have the option to filter that list based on some categories. I then have to sort again the list because it is possible that with the new filtered list, there will be only one name displayed so I don't want to display the sort order by name. So I need to sort just to be able to reset the UISegmentControl. 
Since the sort is taking a few seconds, I pushed it in another thread. Here is my code:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"value"]) {
    //The filter value has changed, so I have to redo the sort

        [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:NULL];
        [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@""];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = false;
        [self.tableView reloadData]; //I reload here because I want to display Loading... on my table (another var has been set before hands so the tableview will display that)

        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
            [self displayAfterFilterChanged];  
        });
}
}

-(void) displayAfterFilterChanged
{
displayState = DISPLAYRUNNING;
[self setupSort];  //<<< this is where the 3 sort index are setup based on the filter
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {  //<<< I call all the UI stuff in the main_queue. (remember that this method has been call from dispatch_async)
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //<< the table will display with the sorted and filtered data 
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = true;
    if (!self.leSelecteur) { //<<< if I don't have a UISegmentControl I display a title text
        [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"atitle"];
    } else { // I have a UISegmentControl, so I use it. 
        [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:self.leSelecteur];
        NSLog(@"before setneedsdisplay");
        [self.navigationItem.titleView setNeedsDisplay];
        NSLog(@"after setneedsdisplay");
    }
});
}
```

NOW, THE PROBLEM:
The table is redisplaying itself right away, the rightbarbuttonitem is enabled right away. 
But the navigationItem titleView takes 5-10 secondes before it display itself. 
Looks like it is skipping a display cycle and catch the next one. 
Is there a way I could speed it up ?
I can see that "before setNeedsdisplay" and "after setneedsdisplay" are displayed on the log right away. But the actual refresh occurs 5-10 sec later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, got it. I was actually building my UISegmentControl in the thread. So I was playing with the UI not in the main thread (bad boy... slap, slap ;) ). I moved all the code to create the control in the block called in the main thread, and voila, it worked. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try changing dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {  in your displayAfterFilterChanged to dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) { this is the only thing about your code that seems off to me.  Because your call to displayAfterFilterChanged  is already running asynchronously I assume you want [self setupSort]; to block and then all of your UI code to run synchronously on the UI thread.

Comment: good catch. At first, it was sync. I changed it to async to try it... no luck. But I changed it back to sync after your comment ... and still no luck :(

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong ... that's how I understand the logic: displayAfterFilterChanged is called on another thread, so the UI is free to do its things.  In there, setupSort runs until completion, then once it is done, the block is dispatch to the main queue.  The reason I'm asking is to make sure that setupSort is blocking.  From what I can see, it is.

Comment: fyi: while I'm waiting for the titleView to display, the UI is not blocked, i.e. I can scroll. So it is not that another task in my code is stealing all the cpu. (I don't have any other threads)

Comment: You understand correctly I do this sort of thing often.  Seems like you've run into some sort of bug or one off in how the navigation item is getting redrawn.  Can you setNeedsDisplay on the navigationBar?

Answer (score 0):

Your UI code should run on the main thread. Don't create a separate thread and perform tasks on the UI.

Comment: isn't what dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() is for ?

Comment: if I don't do it this way, how could I tell back to my main thread that I'm ready to display ? I've tried to use NSNotifications to call back the main thread, but I was having the same delay problem

Comment: ok, got it. I was actually building my UISegmentControl in the thread. So I was playing with the UI not in the main thread (bad boy... slap, slap ;) ). I moved all the code to create the control in the block called in the main thread, and voila, it worked.

thank you all  ( I should answer my own question... but I would have to wait for 8h... So I'm answering in a comment for now)